# Не работают аргументы для тг бота при передаче их через url

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

у меня есть простой тг-бот, суть в том, что в документации есть возможность передачи аргументов с командой start такого вида t.me/your_bot?start=XXXX
но при переходе по ссылке
https://t.me/test_moyset_notifications_bot?start=123

у меня появляется кнопка "start" которая не работает, то есть если сообщения в боте были, тогда при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит и кнопка исчезает.

если истории сообщений нет, тогда появляется кнопка start при первом нажатии на нее ничего не происходит, при повторном нажатии отправляется /start без каких-либо параметров.

ЧатГПТ не знает в чем проблема, я уже думал, что аргументы перестали поддерживаться, но открыл документацию telegram Bot API, в нем говорится что все должно быть окей.

Answer (score 0):

Заработало, проблема была в кэшировании бота в тг!